# Two Models for one Controller

Tags: model-view-controller

Let’s say I have a YouTube-style site, but with images rather than videos. Each user can upload multiple images at a time. I want to store the images in one table, and I want to store the information about the page that displays the images (the images’ “debate” page) in another table — this one has a column where I store the foreign ID of the images that were uploaded and referenced in the database.

Should I create two models and call them both from the same controller?

For example, I could have `createDebateController` create two models — one for storing the debate page info and one for storing the images. Would this be reasonable? If it is, how would I store the `id` of each image in the model that creates the debate page info in the DB?

Comment: Another quick question, is it reasonable to call one model from another?

Comment: what models are you referring to? view model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a model for each, then only reference the debate object through its related image object. So, when posting a new image:

```
$image = new Image();
$image->setImage($file);
$image->setName($name);
$image->save();
```

Then, whenever a comment gets posted, you'd use the image object to indirectly create the debate object:

```
$image->addDebate($user, $timestamp, $comment);
```

Or when rendering the display page:

```
foreach ($image->getDebates() as $debate) {
    $debate->print();
}
```

Your image object would then access the debate object directly:

```
class Image
{

    public function addDebate($user, $timestamp, $comment)
    {
        $debate = new Debate();
        $debate->setImageId($this->id);
        $debate->setUser($user);
        $debate->setTimestamp($timestamp);
        $debate->setComment($comment);
        $debate->save();
    }

    public function getDebates()
    {
        return query("select * from debate where image_id = ?", $this->id);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably use two separate controllers regardless.  One for debates and one for images.  Your debate model (assuming a one-to-many relationship) should have a collection of image ids, or maybe a collection of image descriptors if you need placement or other identifying information for each image.  If you don't need placement information, you simply use the image ids to generate the collection of links to each image using the image controller.   If you do need placement (or description, etc. information) then, the description model has the actual image id.  Yes it is ok to have relationships between your models that are exposed to the view.

Comment: The images are uploaded as part of the debate. I don't see how we could have separate controllers?

Comment: @edwin - the upload form can post back to a method on the images controller, so your image controller would have `upload` and `display` actions.  Your debate controller generates a view that contains forms both for uploading images and adding other things to the page.  When your upload completes (assuming you do a full post instead of using an iframe or flash, etc.), you redirect back to the debate controller action to show the page with the new image. The upload form needs to include the debate id either in the url or as a hidden field so that you know which debate to redirect back to.